# Filter string and null values from object

Tags: javascript

when a value of a property of the object is null or contains "missing" the whole object should be filterd.

this works for filtering null

```
object = (object.filter(o => !Object.values(o).includes(null))
```

But how can I add 2 filters and how to implement a filter that filters strings that contain the word "missing"

```
  object = (object.filter(o => !Object.values(o).includes(null) | ("missing")));
```

object:

```
[
      { id: 'blockstack-iou',
        name: 'Blockstack (IOU)',
        image: 'missing_large.png'
      }
      { id: 'qtum',
        name: 'Qtum',
        image:
         'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/684/large/qtum.png?1547034438',
        price_change_percentage: -53.2869774915231
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.every()`.

Use `&&` to combine multiple tests.

```js
let object = [{
    id: 'blockstack-iou',
    name: 'Blockstack (IOU)',
    image: 'missing_large.png'
  },
  {
    id: 'qtum',
    name: 'Qtum',
    image: 'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/684/large/qtum.png?1547034438',
    price_change_percentage: -53.2869774915231
  }
];

console.log(object.filter(o => Object.values(o).every(prop => 
  prop != null && !prop.toString().includes("missing"))));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a solution that is easily extensible, consider storing all your "conditions" as an array and running through them using `.every()`.

```js
const object = [
  {str: "this_is_missing"},
  {str: null},
  {str: "valid"}
];

const validations = [
  i => i !== null,                          //Value isn't null
  i => !i.toString().includes("missing")    //Value doesn't contain "missing"
];

const validate = (val) => validations.every(fn => fn(val));

const result = object.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).every(validate));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use && and match

```
const object = [
    {id: 'blockstack-iou',
     name: 'Blockstack (IOU)',
     image: 'missing_large.png'
    },
    { id: 'qtum',
    name: 'Qtum',
    image:
    'https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/684/large/qtum.png?1547034438',
    price_change_percentage: -53.2869774915231
    }
  ]
const filtered = (object.filter(o =>!Object.values(o).includes(null) && !Object.values(o).toString().match(/missing/gi)));
console.log(filtered)
```